# Need a virtual touchpad to use my phone which lost the upper half of the screen's touch

Tags: android, mouse

I have a nexus 4 phone, which has lost upper half of the screen's touch capability due to its digitizer problem. I would like to have ["TouchMousePointer Windows app"](http://www.lovesummertrue.com/touchmousepointer/en-us) like app in android.

Required features are listed below in order of importance:

- This app should provide a "virtual touch pad" which can be placed on the screen where touch works. Using this virtual touch pad I should be able to move the mouse pointer (which is available when you connect a PC USB mouse to an OTG capable phone) or a virtual mouse pointer, and thus use the phone.
- Primary use is to do single click on the screen.
- Ability to hide and bring back the "virtual touch pad" should be easier. So that I can use the keyboard without "virtual touch pad" in between.
- Touch's to the rest of the screen should be disabled, so that "ghost touches" can be ignored.
- If drags are supported then it would be cool.

There is already a ["virtual trackball app"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.spyfly.virtualtrackball&hl=en) which just allows to move selection on icons or cursors on text etc.. But I need a mouse pointer and freely move it.

Apart from the usage that I mentioned above I see two more usage:

1. Ability to touch the screen without our finger hiding the screen - useful while drawing.
2. Use larger phones or tablets with your thumb. Thus avoid moving your hand over the screen or avoid using both hands etc...

Comment: I got an alternative way to solve this problem. http://android.stackexchange.com/a/140691/140554

Answer (score 0):

It's only been 3 years since this question was posted...but I have an answer.

think you might like this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.ericytsang.touchpad.app.android

Here's a short video demo of it: https://youtu.be/mklP2CvacKQ

Features:

- can quickly minimize and maximize the virtual cursor...

  - minimize by moving the cursor to the bottom of the screen
  - maximize by dragging from the repositionable always-on-screen mouse icon
- tap, long press, drag, and even pinch.